# Data scraping basketball data using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to return only the names of these 3 players (in the url).. The current code returns their name, their team, and their basketball association. Is there something I can specify in the code to return only names?

Data scraping from [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&type=totals&per_minute_base=36&per_poss_base=100&season_start=1&season_end=-1&lg_id=NBA&age_min=0&age_max=99&is_playoffs=N&height_min=0&height_max=99&year_min=2017&year_max=2017&birth_country_is=Y&as_comp=gt&as_val=0&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=fg3_pct&c1comp=gt&c1val=40&c2stat=fg3a&c2comp=gt&c2val=164&c3stat=dbpm&c3comp=gt&c3val=0&order_by=ws):

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def bball_spider(str):
    source_code = requests.get(str)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

# Players
for elements in soup.find('table' , {'id' : 'stats'}).findAll('a'):
    names = elements.string
    print(names)



str = input("Enter the Query Result URL ")

bball_spider(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, but first let me mention this since it seems you are new to Python: You shouldn't name a variable `str`, because it shadows the built-in *str* class, so that's something I modified in the code shown below. The important modification is that I changed your `.findAll('a')` to `.findAll('td',{'class':'left active'})`, inspecting the element we can see that all the names of the players are in a `<td>` tag with class `left active`. I also changed the iterating var to `element` instead of its plural, so it makes more sense semantically speaking. Also do note the code you posted is not correctly idented, but I think this was just a formatting issue when you pasted it here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bball_spider(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

    # Players
    for element in soup.find('table',{'id' : 'stats'}).findAll('td',{'class':'left active'}):
        names = element.string
        print(names)

url = '''https://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&type=totals&per_minute_base=36&per_poss_base=100&season_start=1&season_end=-1&lg_id=NBA&age_min=0&age_max=99&is_playoffs=N&height_min=0&height_max=99&year_min=2017&year_max=2017&birth_country_is=Y&as_comp=gt&as_val=0&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=fg3_pct&c1comp=gt&c1val=40&c2stat=fg3a&c2comp=gt&c2val=164&c3stat=dbpm&c3comp=gt&c3val=0&order_by=ws'''
bball_spider(url)
```

---

This will print:

```
Chris Paul
Otto Porter
Joe Ingles
```